# google maps: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps') in react

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps api in React and so far everything has been working fine. However, after I add an useEffect in another component, that is rendered at the same time as the component, which has Google Maps I get: `typeerror: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')`.

This is the useEffect in Maps.js (where the error occurs - in line `const position = new window.google.maps.LatLng(data[key].lat, data[key].lng)`):

```
  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    googleMapsApiKey: '...',
    libraries: ['places'],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const databaseRef = ref(rtdb, 'markers/'+user.uid);
    get(databaseRef)
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          const data = snapshot.val();
            const position = new window.google.maps.LatLng(data[key].lat, data[key].lng);

          })
        } 
      })
  }, []);
```

When I add this useEffect function into notifications-popover.js the above error occurs:

```
  useEffect(() => {
     const eventsRef = ref(rtdb, `calendar/${user.uid}`);
  });
```

This one line in useEffect in notifications-popover.js causes the error, which makes me think that something regarding loading the api is ruined by the second useEffect.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates this issue. A link to a working codesandbox would be nice.